# Strange behavior of Nmap

Tags: nmap, ports, kali-linux

I do port scanning with Nmap when HotSpot Shield VPN is running; and I am receiving strange result - when HotSpot Shield is running, Nmap tells me that all of the ports are open and when HotSpot is not running, Nmap gives correct result .

I examine this on my Internet server. And problem occurs. Why?

Comment: because this is about the behaviour of a specific product, you might want to submit a support request to the vendor: https://support.hotspotshield.com/hc/en-us/requests/new

Answer (score 0):

HotSpot shield may be using an active response to handle as a intrusion detection / prevention and to prevent network abuse.  Probably a lot of users may be using their service in order to perform port scans, and HotSpot is protecting itself.

So, it may be their firewall / gateway / ... sending you a response, not the rteal target.

Comment: Hi , If this is true , then every admin can use such firewall and such firewall's configurations , and forever be safe from Nmappers